# $W_1+W_2$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $W_1$ and $W_2$, where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We know that $W_1+W_2$ is also a subspace of $V$.
How do you prove that $W_1+W_2$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $W_1$ and $W_2$?
Considering $U$ as another subspace of $V$ containing $W_1$ and $W_2$ is the way to proceed.
But aren't $W_1+W_2$ and $U$ equal?

Comment: Whay? Why can't $U$ be the whole space $V$ and $W_1+W_2$ a proper subspace?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you claiming that every subspace of $V$ containing $W_1$ and $W_2$ has to be equal to $W_1+W_2$?

Comment: No , not exactly but can't that be a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $U\supset W_1$ and $U\supset W_2$, then, since $U$ is a subspace, if $w_1\in W_1$ and $w_2\in W_2$, then $w_1+w_2\in U$. Therefore, $U\supset W_1+W_2$. Since every subspace of $V$ containing $W_1$ and $W_2$ contains $W_1+W_2$ and since $W_1+W_2$ is a subspace of $V$ containing $W_1$ and $W_2$, $W_1+W_2$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $W_1$ and $W_2$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: Perhaps you you could consider the possibility of accepting my answer.

Comment: Yes, this answer does work. Thanks!

Comment: Then why don't you accept it? All you have to do is to click on the ✓ sign.

Comment: Yeah. I have clicked.